# Add img in view react native

Tags: image, react-native, view

I'll try to have a panel with free img.

I have a global view who contains

```js
import React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, View, Image } from 'react-native';

class Search extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
                <View style={{ flex: 1, height: 335 }}>
                    <Image source={{ uri: "./images/images1.jpg" }} />
                </View>
                <View style={{ flex: 1, height: 335 }}>
                    <Image source={{ uri: "./images/images2.jpg" }} />
                </View>
                <View style={{ flex: 1, height: 335 }}>
                    <Image source={{ uri: "./images/images3.jpg" }} />
                </View>
            </View>
        )
    }
}
export default Search
```

My problem is when I call in my controller the component:

```js
import React from 'react';
import Search from './Components/Search'

export default function App() {
    return (
        <Search />
    );
}
```

My image isn't displayed on my screen. I have just a white screen.

What's wrong in my code to show my images?

Comment: Can you try add a width and height to each Image component ?

Comment: I have try but any change

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to change your code like this:

```
import React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, View, Image } from 'react-native';

class Search extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
                <View style={{ flex: 1, height: 335 }}>
                    <Image source={require('./images/images1.jpg')} />
                </View>
                <View style={{ flex: 1, height: 335 }}>
                <Image source={require('./images/images2.jpg')} />
                </View>
                <View style={{ flex: 1, height: 335 }}>
                <Image source={require('./images/images3.jpg')} />
                </View>
            </View>
        )
    }
}
export default Search
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

You need to require to get the image.

```js
class Search extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
                <View style={{ flex: 1, height: 335 }}>
                    <Image source={{ uri: require("./images/images1.jpg") }} />
                </View>
                <View style={{ flex: 1, height: 335 }}>
                    <Image source={{ uri: require("./images/images2.jpg") }} />
                </View>
                <View style={{ flex: 1, height: 335 }}>
                    <Image source={{ uri: require("./images/images3.jpg") }} />
                </View>
            </View>
        )
    }
}
export default Search
```

Comment: When I put a require I have the error: Json value "2" of type NSNumber cannot be converted to a valid url